# HTML5, take images from one div and put into another right aligned

Tags: html, alignment

When I put images from one div to another, they are left aligned. I want them right aligned .

Comment: use `float:right ` in css

Comment: Hi tursun, is your question already solved?

Comment: @RonnieOosting, yes what albin paul said was right. images dropped shown on the right , not on the left. however i found another issue: i want images dropped on the right also when second and rest dropped they should not push previous one to the left, but itself comes to left side of what dropped earlier. how to show my code?

Comment: I suggest to pick an answer as the answer, and create a new question. You can show your code simply by copy pasting it into your question

Comment: @RonnieOosting, thank you for prompt answer. i midified my post anyway. it is up there now. any idea about solution bro?

Comment: To  be honest I think best is to mark your first question as solved and create a new question. Because you are asking a new question within your first question.

Comment: @RonnieOosting, i will do as you said. This question is properly answered. So I gonna mark it SOLVED.

Comment: ok, the new question is here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897877/html5-drag-images-and-drop-into-right-side-of-div-images-concatenate-right-to-l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below will show you the image is floated right.

**Code:**

```
<style>
    img {
        float: right;
    }
</style>

<p>In this example, the image will float to the right</p>

<p><img src="someimage.jpg" alt="image" style="width:100px;height:100;margin-left:15px;">
    Text blablabla. Lorim Ipsum...</p>
```

Just copy paste this and see the result. From there on you can edit your CSS.

Comment: what if next images comes? say, i want it to come to the left hand side of previous image? currently mine, new image always kick old one to the left.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about alignment so that the images are next to one another, a quick way to do it is using [float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) where you have each individual image float next to one another using CSS. As an
example:

```
.class {
float: right
}
```

The better way to have these images aligned may be using [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which will allow you to have a better control over where each precise image/text you want to have located.

Comment: Welscome to StackOverflow! Could you expand on how you might using flex? Using hyperlinks are useful for answers but it is recommended that they are explained in a bit more detail: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers